# Why sometimes I can't access jQuery object in some sites in my chrome console?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, console

Sometimes I can use jQuery for any websites in chrome console but sometimes it's said that $ is undefined. Even though I am pretty sure that jQuery library is included.

For example:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels

This page uses jQuery but in the console I just can't access the $ object.

Comment: Possibly `jQery.noConflict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes jQuery is not assigned to the $ symbol. Run this to make it work as expected:

```
 if ($ === undefined) {$=jQuery} else {alert("$ is occupied already")};
```

Comment: This could break something that's currently using `$`, though. It would be a lot safer to just use `jQuery`.

Comment: Changed it to take that into consideration

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement when using jQuery to alias it to $. Sometimes another library needs $ or sometimes using `jQuery()` instead is not a bother so no need to alias. Sometimes `jQuery.noConlict()` changes the alias.